# Optimising SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedures

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

**Update 25/03/2011**
I've marked this question as answered, while I don't yet have the specific answers to help improve the system I don't think it's fair to hold off until I've gone that far.  The question was broad, and the answers have given me lots of pointers to help me on my way.  When I have more specific questions to ask i'll be back with those.  Unfortunately I can only mark one answer with the tick, but I want to thank everyone for their input, it's *all* been valuable, thanks for your time.

**Original Question**

Apologies in advance as this question is going to probably be quite broad!

I'm literally just about to step in to a project where one of our other developers has put together a massive system based around SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition, Reporting Services and Stored Procedures.  What we've found in performance testing on a VM system (i.e. where SQL Server is running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 system hosted by VMWare1 ESXi) is that it does not appear to take advantage of extra memory or cores.

As I get in to this project I was looking for some guidance about some initial outline questions:

1. What are the opportunities for optimising to make use of more memory and more processor cores within SQL Server 2008?
2. Are there rules regarding how the stored procedures are called, structured, developed etc that will influence how SQL Server can parallelise the stored procedures?

Further, I guess the next obvious point is - what are the things I need to look out for in the code that might provide more insight to others as to how it's structured and allow me to provide more specific examples? There are a *lot* of lines of code in the system, but obviously the ideal is to try and find a condensed example or pattern that demonstrates usage.

The Stored Procedures are, I believe, called by Reporting Services.

In our tests it almost seems that it's linear execution - i.e. if we configure the VM with 2 cores, 2ghz CPU allocation, and 4gb of memory, if 1 report concurrently runs in 2 minutes, 2 will take nearly 4 minutes (i.e. twice the time for *both* reports), it's not quite as linear as that but close enough - everything gets slower almost as though they aren't really running in parallel at all.

Could it be SQL Server Reporting Services is simply only running reports one at a time or something related to that?

Stored procedures are all developed in Transact-SQL.

Again, apologies for the broad question.  If there's someone out there that can help educate me in how to get deeper and more knowledgeable in this area then that would be *most* appreciated!

Matt.

Comment: what version of SQL Server (year: 2005 or 2008) and edition(enterprise, express, etc.)

Comment: @RacerX "SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition" (2nd para)

Comment: how much data are the reports trying to process?  what's the data size?  what, exactly, are the sp's being ran by the report doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things to keep in mind

1. Memory is your friend, the more you
   have the less SQL Server has to go
   to disk which is 1000 times slower
2. Do you have the correct indexes and
   are they used?
3. Are your where clauses/order by
   covered by indexes?
4. is the where clause sargable or is
   it written in a way that SQL Server
   won't use the index?
5. Are the procs using a SET based
   operation or is it using cursors and
   looping through data sets (which is
   way slower)
6. Are the procs using SELECT * when
   only really 2 columns are needed?
7. Separate Log, tempdb and data files
   on their own disk spindle, if you
   have non clustered indexes also put
   those on their own disk
8. While the procs are running use
   performance monitor or even task
   manager and look at what
   happens...is CPU maxed..is RAM maxed
9. Is one report blocking the other?
   run `EXEC sp_who2` and look at the
   BlkBy column
10. Grab one of the procs, run it in
     SSMS and look at the execution
     plan..if you see a lot of scans and
     high % of total execution
     items..first focus on those, also look for things like conversions in the plan

Can you show some code, we can quickly look at it and tell you if we see red flag

Comment: Oddly, if we go from 2gb of memory on the VM to 4gb of memory on the VM it doesn't seem to make much of a difference.  I'll be getting access to the code shortly and will try and provide more detail with specific examples at that point.  The performance of the queries when only one use is concurrently accessing the system is quite acceptable (obviously we always want it faster) - the issue is just that if two people hit it at the same time everything goes half the speed, even if we double the number of cores.  Thanks for your response!

Comment: @Matt - You can look at `sys.dm_os_schedulers` whilst the concurrent activity is occurring to get some insight into how the load is distributed across cores.

Comment: Look at CPU and Disk IO, it could also be that you just started up the VM and everything is still on disk and nothing is cached

Comment: Are you getting locks when both report queries are run?

Comment: If you do not have indexes or do not take advantage of them then there will be a high CPU usage. That leads inevitable to poor performance when there are multiple selections.

Comment: @SQLMenace - We run all our tests three times and ignore the first one as it's always much slower than the next two, which are always around the same time.  The general pattern of degradation is always about the same though.

Comment: All - Thanks for the great feedback, I think I need to go and get some tests run based on this and get some answers now!

Comment: @Dumitrescu - Yes I believe there are indexes and I believe they are correct however that is indeed one of the areas I will be reviewing to make sure they are indeed correct for our usage.

Answer (score 3):

if from the same connection you make two procedure calls, they will run consecutive.  That is, one will run and when it is complete the next one will run.

from one connection, if you a procedure and at the same time from a different connection run a procedure, they will run simultaneiosly, depending on locking conditions.

Comment: Given the stored procedures are, I believe, kicked off by Reporting Services, would this likely be using a single connection or multiple? Or can this be influenced in some way?

Comment: are you kicking off a single report that calls two procedures, then they are running one after the other. if you run two reports at the same time then they would run at the same time, as long as they are not locking each other.

Comment: Yes this would be basically two users of the ASP.NET Web app each firing off a report, so my expectation would be two completely separate reports being generated, in theory concurrently.  I guess one thing to test (beyond the locking checks suggested above) would be to manually call the stored procedures via two separate connections explicitly and see if they work more performantly (i.e. to point the finger at reporting services or the stored procedures).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

when it comes to virtualization, brent ozar is your best friend.  [Virtualization Best Bractices](http://www.brentozar.com/sql/virtualization-best-practices/)

Also, is the dat athe reports pulling optimized for the reports?  If not then it'll take a lot of processing on the sql side and report side to render the reports.  you might need to develop some sort of olap process if the oltp system is under a lot of use.  You also might consider cacheing the reports depending on the requirements for the reports.

Another thing is to check to the max memory setting for sql server, if it's set to 2 gb max, adding antoher 4gb isn't going to do you a whole lot of good.